# td:nth-of-type('+element+') not working in casperjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping, casperjs

I want to get text of all td's inside the table with the class .fmBigTbl .
When I hard code the no's instead of giving `piElements`, for eg `td:nth-of-type(2)`. The above works but when I use a variable instead of a number it outputs null.

How can I loop through all the td's in the table?

```
 piElements = 1;
 var data;
 var count = 5;
 this.repeat(count, function() {
      this.then(function() {
         data = this.evaluate(function() {
             return  $('.fmBigTbl').find('td:nth-of-type('+piElements+').fmLblCell2').text();
         });
         this.echo(data);
         piElements++;
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`evaluate` is sandboxed. The inside (page context) cannot simply access variables in outer scope (casper context). You need to pass `piElements` explicitly into `evaluate`:

```
data = this.evaluate(function(piElements) {
    return  $('.fmBigTbl').find('td:nth-of-type('+piElements+').fmLblCell2').text();
}, piElements);
```

From the [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.

or you could simply use `casper.fetchText`:

```
data = this.fetchText('.fmBigTbl td:nth-of-type('+piElements+').fmLblCell2');
```